# Periodic sorting of n product types

Tags: algorithm, sorting

we recently stumpled upon this problem.

We have n different product types, where each product type might have an arbitrary  amount(>=0) of products. We want to "sort" all the products (all products in all types) in a list, however, some product types are to be inserted in the list at a periodic order.

I'd like to explain by using an example:
We have 3 different product types (ProdA, ProdB, ProdC), and 3 units of ProdA, 4 units of ProdB and 2 units of ProdC. ProdC is to be inserted in the list with a period of 2.

One ordering could be:

- ProdA1
- ProdA2
- ProdC1
- ProdA3
- ProdB1
- ProdC2
- ProdB2
- ProdB3
- ProdC1
- ProdB4

Look how, since ProdC is periodic and only has 2 units, the units are repeated when we run out of ProdC units.

If one unit of ProdA and one unit of ProdB is deleted, we want the list to look like this:

- ProdA1
- ProdA2
- ProdC1
- ProdB1
- ProdB2
- ProdC2
- ProdB3

We do not want to "recompute" the whole list.

My question is: **Is there a general algorithm for doing this, which includes dynamic "resorting"?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the sorting rules better please?

Comment: Some product types have to be inserted in a periodic way after the non-periodic ones have been inserted

Comment: Please clarify (with an example) what you mean with "periodic way" and "non-periodic way". What do you mean by "some" have to be inserted that way? Does that mean half, 1/3, 1/4?

Comment: Look at the example in the question. ProdA and ProdB are just inserted in the list in a non-periodic way (we just add all the units). After that, ProdC is inserted in a periodic way (period of 2 product-units)

Comment: So make fixed grid of periodic items and insert non-periodic ones in the free places

Comment: That's all good in creating the list, but how does one handle "updates" to the list (i.e. new unit of ProdC or ProdB added), without recomputing the whole list?

Comment: There's no way of not "recomputing" the list in some way. Maybe run through the list and check where the last element of ProdXn is, and inserting the next one there?

Comment: What structure is used to store the list?

Comment: The list is simply...a list. And we are free to choose the structure we like. When the units changes (deleted or added) we can recompute a new list, and look at the diff between the new list and the original list. Then we can minimize the amount of actions required to make the original lists like the new list

Answer (score 1):

No. Once the list is modified the positions for non periodic ProdA, ProdB change. So, if the list is an array, its memory has changed. If the list is a linked list, the node pointers change.

I suggest to use two list: one with ProdA and ProdB and the other with just ProdC. You can build the merged list when it's needed.

Comment: Due to the nature of the problem, we want to avoid as much "interference/recomputing" in the original list as possible. And we cannot rebuild the list. One way could be to rebuild a new list, and look at the diff between the new list and the original list and try to minimze the amount of action required in the original list to make the original list like the new list

Comment: Once you have the modification location, only the first part of the list remains valid. The rest (after the location) must be changed and/or resized. How is this cheaper that a whole rebuild? (i'm thinking of new memory allocations)

Comment: Well, a linked list may be cheaper in terms of new memory. But not by means of "interference".